# Adding a function to a string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains a column with countries.
I want to convert the country names to capital cities.
Example of how the function works:

```py
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
    
CountryInfo('Lebanon').capital()
```

Would return `Beirut`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `lambda` function and `pd.apply()` like this:

```py
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
df['Capital'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x : CountryInfo(x).capital()
```

Here you can put your own `df's column name` in place of  `'Capital'` and `'country'`.